# how to extract data from html table with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I extract specific data from the followed table such as decay time 91.1 ms 5?

```
<table bgcolor=navy cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 align=center> 
  <tr class=hp >
    <td nowrap>E(level) (MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>J&pi;</td><td nowrap>&Delta;(MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>T<sub>1/2</sub></td>
    <td nowrap>Decay Modes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=cp>
    <td nowrap valign=top>0.0</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>4+</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> 18.2010</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>91.1 ms <i>5</i>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> &epsilon; : 100.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;p : 55.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;2p : 1.10 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;&alpha; : 0.04 &#37;<br> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: do you have this html in a file or do you already have it in a string?

Comment: I have added an answer to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ususally if I see a `<table>` tag, using pandas `.read_html()` is my first thing to try. It'll retunr a list of dataframes. It's then just a matter of selecting the dataframe and manipulating the dataframe to get it the way you want, or to pull the data you need:

```
import pandas as pd


html = '''<table bgcolor=navy cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 align=center> 
  <tr class=hp >
    <td nowrap>E(level) (MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>J&pi;</td><td nowrap>&Delta;(MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>T<sub>1/2</sub></td>
    <td nowrap>Decay Modes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=cp>
    <td nowrap valign=top>0.0</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>4+</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> 18.2010</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>91.1 ms <i>5</i>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> &epsilon; : 100.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;p : 55.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;2p : 1.10 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;&alpha; : 0.04 &#37;<br> </td>
  </tr>
</table>'''

tables = pd.read_html(html)
df = tables[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
df = df.iloc[1:,:]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.loc[1,'T1/2'])
91.1 ms 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple code to put that table into a pandas dataframe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = """<table cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 align=center> 
  <tr class=hp >
    <td nowrap>E(level) (MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>J&pi;</td>
    <td nowrap>&Delta;(MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>T<sub>1/2</sub></td>
    <td nowrap>Decay Modes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=cp>
    <td nowrap valign=top>0.0</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>4+</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> 18.2010</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>91.1 ms <i>5</i>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> &epsilon; : 100.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;p : 55.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;2p : 1.10 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;&alpha; : 0.04 &#37;<br> </td>
  </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
headers = soup.find('tr', {'class':'hp'}).findAll('td')
columns = []
for header in headers:
    columns.append(header.text)

data = []
data_raw = soup.findAll('tr',{'class':'cp'})
for row in data_raw:
    items = []
    for element in row.findAll('td'):
        items.append(element.text)
    data.append(items)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

print(df['T1/2'])
```

Output is:

```
0    91.1 ms 5 
Name: T1/2, dtype: object
```

If what you have in **Decay Modes** are multiple rows you may have to add additional code to detect that (they are separated by `<br>`), or if you can, correct the HTML to have different rows within different row tags and the header in a header tag

Comment: Thanks for your helpful and kindly answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table by using `get_element_by_tag_name` and iterate through each of the inner tags and get the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the markup already in a string. You have to find the elements by class (.cp), then you have to find by tag (td), and you can get the value of each found element using `.text` atribute, so use the following code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<table bgcolor=navy cellpadding=4 cellspacing=1 border=0 align=center> 
  <tr class=hp >
    <td nowrap>E(level) (MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>J&pi;</td><td nowrap>&Delta;(MeV)</td>
    <td nowrap>T<sub>1/2</sub></td>
    <td nowrap>Decay Modes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=cp>
    <td nowrap valign=top>0.0</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>4+</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> 18.2010</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top>91.1 ms <i>5</i>&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap valign=top> &epsilon; : 100.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;p : 55.00 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;2p : 1.10 &#37;<br>  &epsilon;&alpha; : 0.04 &#37;<br> </td>
  </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("cp"))

for e in elements[0].find_all('td'):
    # the e.text contains the value of each td elements in your table
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: @Brad, would you mind validating the answer that helped you?